# PHP not getting variables from jscript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have trying to create a php cart and I have a table with a couple of products, when I click on the submit button some javascript is called and then the form is submitted.
When I execute the page and press the button I get a page "productcart.php?productid=1&command=add" and chrome says that there is an internal server error. I believe that there is a jscript or PHP error that is not letting the variables be pulled into the php code block. Can anyone see if there is something else I am doing wrong?
also what does the "?productid=1&command=add" mean? why does the browser return that?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function addtocart(prod_id)
 {
  document.productform.productid.value = prod_id;
  document.productform.command.value = 'add';
  document.productform.submit();
 }
 </script>
```

```html
<?php
 include("local-connect.php");
 include("productfunctions.php");
 
 if($_REQUEST['command'] == 'add' && $_REQUEST['productid'] > 0)
 {
  $product_id = $_REQUEST['productid'];
  add_to_cart($product_id, 1);
  echo 'it worked';
  //header("Location:cart.php");
  exit();
 }
?>

<form name="productform" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="productid" />
  <input type="hidden" name="command" />
  
 <table id="product_table">
 <?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die ("Error querying database");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo '<tr>
   <td><img id="shopping_img" src="' .$row['image'] . '"/></td>
   <td><p><strong>' . $row['name'] . '</strong></p>
   <p>' . $row['descri'] . '</p>
   <p>Price:<strong>&#36;' . $row['price'] . '</strong></p></td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(' . $row['id'] . ')" /></td>
   </tr>';
  }
 ?>
 </table>
 
 </form>
```

Comment: check your server's error log for details about the 500.

Comment: *also what does the "?productid=1&command=add" mean? why does the browser return that?* Because that is a GET request since a GET is the default value for the method for forms.

Comment: You should edit your `php.ini` and enable error logging. Debugging without them is really tough. You can either set `display_errors` or `log_errors` to `On`: http://php.net/log-errors

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the "?productid=1&command=add" in the URL and protect from code injection.
I added method="post" and used $_POST I also used intval() to insure an integer is sent to your function.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function addtocart(prod_id)
 {
  document.productform.productid.value = prod_id;
  document.productform.command.value = 'add';
  document.productform.submit();
 }
 </script>
```

```html
<?php
 include("local-connect.php");
 include("productfunctions.php");
 
 if($_POST['command'] == 'add' && $_POST['productid'] > 0)
 {
  $product_id = intval($_POST['productid']);
  add_to_cart($product_id, 1);
  echo 'it worked';
  //header("Location:cart.php");
  exit();
 }
?>

<form name="productform" action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="productid" />
  <input type="hidden" name="command" />
  
 <table id="product_table">
 <?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die ("Error querying database");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo '<tr>
   <td><img id="shopping_img" src="' .$row['image'] . '"/></td>
   <td><p><strong>' . $row['name'] . '</strong></p>
   <p>' . $row['descri'] . '</p>
   <p>Price:<strong>&#36;' . $row['price'] . '</strong></p></td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(' . $row['id'] . ')" /></td>
   </tr>';
  }
 ?>
 </table>
 
 </form>
```